# Detect files of folders which do not inherit permissions from their parent

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, file-permissions, permissions

Is there an easy way to find any files/folders (recursively) within a directory which do not inherit permissions from their parent.  i.e. To gauge the effects of selecting "replace permissions on child objects" before committing to it?  i.e. Without manually trawling through every object under the selected directory.

Powershell, command line, or third party tools welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe AccessEnum from the SysInternals suite will do precisely what you need.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx